# Excel VLOOKUP, files in sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, excel-formula

we have a lot of files in sharepoint that many users work whit.
This fliles used to be in a shared folder in a server, and the vlookup function worked fine.

Now we have thos same files in sharepoint, if we sinc the files to a local folder for the user A, the user A can use the VLOOKUP function, but it only works for the user A becouse the VLOOKUP function takes the path of the pc of user A, when a user B sincs the file, the file shows an error cuse the VLOOKUP function points to a path that dont exists in the pc of user b.

Any ideas or we have to go back and have it in a shared folder in a server?

Comment: Maybe use a power query data connection?

Answer (score 0):

In the end we moved the files to a shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this but its a bit hacky - it requires that the mounted drive of everyone be in the same location and then you need to find the username of the persons windows account, so that you create the path name for each person.

But here is some code that will do it.

GetUserName = Environ$("username")

localpath = "C:\Users" & GetUserName & "\SomeFileLocationHere"

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found a way around this.  It DOES depend on users having access to the files that are being referenced.  The trick is that you can VLOOKUP across multiple files stored on OneDrive/Sharepoint BUT they all have to be OPEN at the same time.

My situation has users entering a value and then several subsequent values are populated via VLOOKUP from 3 files.  I set it up where the VLOOKUPs use the **'https:/sharepoint server/folder/file'!Table** hard reference. Once the user has entered a value on their sheet (or they can go ahead and enter a series of values) they can then press an UPDATE button that has a macro assigned to it.  The macro simply opens the 3 files that the VLOOKUPs reference, saves the users file where the VLOOKUPs live and have now populated, and then closes the 3 reference files.